# Image larger than screen (intended). How to implement touch features

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, touch

I tried to google my problem but I don't really know how to word it in a brief enough way :/

Basically I have this image which is larger than the screen.  Its in the view and its View Mode is set to the Top Left.  I know how to drag an image around the screen, but I basically want to drag the view around the image, if you get me?  Could anyone direct me to some example code or briefly explain the steps involved in this?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Most likely I don't understand you properly, but maybe you should use UIImageVIew within UIScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a UIImageView inside of a UIScrollView and then set them up similar to this.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
CGSize imageSize = image.size;
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
self.imageView.image = image;
self.scrollView.contentSize = imageSize;
```